# zf2 redirect with query string containing + instead of %20

Tags: php, redirect, zend-framework, zend-framework2

In ZF2, I know I can create a 301 redirect with a query string appended like this:

```
$options = [ 
    'query' => [
        'string' => 'hello world', 
    ]
];

return $this->redirect()
            ->toRoute('myRoute', [], $options)
            ->setStatusCode(301);
```

However, this redirects to a URL with `hello%20world` appended. In ZF2, is there a way to write this redirect with `hello+world` appended instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since ZF2 does not offer a native function to redirect with a query string using `urlencode` instead of `rawurlencode`, we wrote a custom method which redirects. Not exactly pretty, but solves our problem for now:

```
private function redirectToPageFive($query)
{   
    $location = ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ? 'https://' : 'http://')
              . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
              . '/search?query='
              . urlencode($query)
              . '&page=5';

    header("Location: $location", true, 301);
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your url is being properly `url_encode`d. It's being as much as "transformed" as put into valid characters for a URL.

On the receiving end, your `"hello%20world"` is going to be received as  `"hello world"` automatically.

There is nothing to fix, code is working as intended.

Comment: +0 Actually, the string is not `urlencode`d. It is `rawurlencode`d, which results in the `%20` rather than the prefered `+`. We need one unique URL for every search query. Therefore we need to redirect to `hello+world` instead of `hello%20world`. The code as it exists may perform as originally intended, but we need the option to `urlencode` rather than `rawurlencode`.